# Using cURL to view contents of file

Tags: curl, cmd, get, command, prompt

I am trying to figure out the command to display the contents of a file (text file) in command prompt using cURL and get. I had the right command but now I can't seem to get the correct syntax right to display the proper file information:

curl -g host:port@path to file
curl -d filename-g host:port

I have tried many variations of the above and have consulted the cURL manual:

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

And other SO resources...Just need a little boost here as I had the correct syntax but now have spent several hours trying to get the proper terminology.

Comment: i didnt get: u need to get file content?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question right. To view the contents of a file in the filesystem you can use 'cat', you use 'curl' to retrieve (or send) data to an URL. Why do you think you need the parameters '-g' and '-d'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use ...

```
curl http://example.com/file
```

Or eventually

```
 curl http://example.com:8888/file
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, using Git Bash, to print out the contents of a local file using cURL:

```
curl file://C:/Projects/hello-curl/doc.json
```